# How to iterate over a google.protobuf.ListValue

Tags: go, iteration, protocol-buffers, grpc

My Protocol buffer specification looks like this:

```
message CreateContextRequest {
  map<string, google.protobuf.ListValue> my_mapping = 2;
}
```

My Go code that uses this protocol buffer looks like this:

```
1:   fmt.Println("protocBuff = ", protocBuff);
2:   fmt.Println("protocBuff.MyMapping = ", protocBuff.MyMapping);
3:   for myKey, myListValue := range protocBuff.MyMapping {
4:      fmt.Println("myKey:", myKey, "=>", "myListValue:", myListValue)
5:      for _, element := range myListValue {
6:          fmt.Printf("element = ", element)
7:      }
8:   }
```

Lines 1-4 work fine. But line #5 gives this compile-time error: `cannot range over myListValue (type *structpb.ListValue)`

So how can I iterate over myListValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of [ListValue](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb#ListValue) (with private fields removed) is:

```
type ListValue struct {
    // Repeated field of dynamically typed values.
    Values []*Value `protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=values,proto3" json:"values,omitempty"`
}
```

So to iterate through this you can use:

- `for _, element := range myListValue.Values`
- `for _, element := range myListValue.GetValues()` (safer as it checks for `nil` `myListValue`)
- `for _, element := range myListValue.AsSlice()` (may be better, depends upon what you are doing with the values).